# Attaching Lambda Triggers to a Cognito UserPool in Cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm looking to customise the email message Cognito sends out to a new user when you call `adminCreateUser()`

I can see you do this via Lambda functions, eg -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    if(event.userPoolId === "theSpecialUserPool") {
        if(event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser") {
            event.response.smsMessage = "Welcome to the service. Your user name is " + event.request.usernameParameter + " Your temporary password is " + event.request.codeParameter;
            event.response.emailSubject = "Welcome to the service";
            event.response.emailMessage = "Welcome to the service. Your user name is " + event.request.usernameParameter + " Your temporary password is " + event.request.codeParameter;
        }
    }
    callback(null, event);
};
```

I can also see that `AWS::Cognito::UserPool` has a `LambdaConfig` object, with a `CustomMessage` field

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig.html

So is looks like this is the attachment point `:)`

However what I can't see is the precise attachment mechanism `:(`

The `CustomMessage` field definition is cryptic -

```
CustomMessage

A custom Message AWS Lambda trigger.

Required: No
Type: String
Minimum: 20
Maximum: 2048
Pattern: arn:[\w+=/,.@-]+:[\w+=/,.@-]+:([\w+=/,.@-]*)?:[0-9]+:[\w+=/,.@-]+(:[\w+=/,.@-]+)?(:[\w+=/,.@-]+)?

Update requires: No interruption
```

ie it's just a `String` - but is that `String`

- an `ARN` ?
- a `Ref` ?
- an inline Lambda body declaration ?

Anyone know which of the above format the `LambdaConfig.CustomMessage` binding supports ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the validation pattern for the string value of `CustomMessage`, it looks like it supports an ARN since the string must contain `arn`.

Comment: @Justin No worries :)